# Migrating Angular 9 to angular 11 : get data from realtimefirebase

Tags: angular, typescript, firebase-realtime-database

I am in the process of migrating an angular 9 application to angular 11. I am using realtime database from firebase.

```
getProjects(code: string){

 return this.database.list('/project', ref => {
    return ref.orderByChild('entity_id').equalTo(code);}).snapshotChanges().pipe(map(actions => {
       return actions.map(a => {
          const data: Object = a.payload.val();
          const key = a.payload.key;
          return {key, ...data };  
       });
    })
 );}
```

This data reading service was working fine, now I have this error:

> Type 'unknown' is not assignable to type 'Object'

I tried to change data type to any but i can't receive my data.
Thanks for your help

Comment: does `const data: Object = <Object>a.payload.val();` fix it?

Comment: yes simply fix ! thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
const data: Object = <Object>a.payload.val();
```

Comment: Please add further details to expand on your answer, such as working code or documentation citations.